# Unable to get child container from DependencyResolver in RequestContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am using Unity as my dependency resolver in an ASP.Net Web API. I used the dependency injection tutorial from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

When trying to use the child container created in BeginScope, all I get is the parent container.

I'm trying to use it in an ActionFilterAttribute with the following code:

```
httpActionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.DependencyResolver
```

and

```
httpActionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.DependencyResolver
```

In both cases, it returns the Parent container and not the child container that was created for that particular request when BeginScope was called.

How can I get the child container to resolve dependencies? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs), I realized the container was saved under:

```
request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.DependencyScope]
```

All I had to do was to get it from here:

```
var resolver = httpActionContext.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.DependencyScope] as IDependencyResolver;
```